# What makes special a volcanic pipe to be stable until the mantle?

Tags: geophysics, volcanology, mantle

Comming from this question:

[Can we really travel through earth's core?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/246/can-we-really-travel-through-earths-core)

I wonder what makes special a [volcanic pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcanic_pipe) to be stable since the mantle through the surface, in comparison to [our try](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole) or expectatives to drill a superhole.

[image]

<sub>Souce of the image: [British Geological Survey](https://www.bgs.ac.uk/discovering-geology/earth-hazards/volcanoes/how-volcanoes-form/)</sub>

---

What's the physics behind this nature success?

Comment: There is a slight misconception in the question - the magma source isn't the mantle. Magma for volcanoes originates in the upper 5 to 10 kilometres of the crust.

Comment: @Andy M What about kimberlites? I am gonna publish a mineral guide app that list minerals with a [mineralogy teacher](https://sideral.unizar.es/sideral/CV/maria-jose-mayayo-burillo) and for diamonds she says the environment of formation is not igneous, is mantelic

Comment: Yes, Kimberlites are an example of mantle derived magma, but are very much the exception rather than the rule. The process of these deep magmas migrating upwards towards the surface is perhaps more like a bubble, less dense than it's surroundings and so buoyant, forcing its way upwards, rather than of a 'pipe'.

Comment: @Andy M Well, but there are volcanic pipes with more than 10.000km